# Rails Custom Validation method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I am fairly new to Rails validations. I have an Activity model that has many attributes (listed in attributes array below). I need to validate that every activity has a name and a at least one of the other attributes. I was think of something like the following but it looks a little messy. Any advice?

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validate :valid_activity

  def valid_activity
    attributes = [reps, distance, meal, post_meal, yoga, reminder, duration]
    if name.present? && self.include? (activity)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You would create a new validator class like so

```
class ActivityValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def valid_activity
    attributes = [:reps, :distance, :meal, :post_meal, :yoga, :reminder, :duration]
    unless name.present? && attributes.any?{ |a| self.activity == a }
      errors[:user] << 'Need to add an activity'
    end
  end
```

end

Then in your `user.rb` file, include the validator module and use the `validates_with` method.

```
include ActiveModel::Validations
validates_with ActivityValidator
```